Set properties of objects in array; Object variable or With block variable not set
I have two classes, park:
Option Explicit

Public card_no As String
Public entry_time As Date
Public exit_time As Date

And park_array (initialize(init_size as integer) and trim() excluded as they are working as intended):
Option Explicit

Private elements() As park
Private size As Integer

Public Sub append(new_card_no As String, new_entry_time As Date, new_exit_time As Date)
    If UBound(elements) < size + 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve elements(size * 2)
    End If

    elements(size).card_no = new_card_no
    
    size = size + 1
End Sub

Called as such:
Option Explicit

Public Sub count_overage(data As Range)
    Dim parks As New park_array
    parks.initialize 200
    
    Dim rw As Range
   
    For Each rw In data.Rows
        parks.append CStr(rw.Cells(2).Value), CDate(rw.Cells(3).Value), CDate(rw.Cells(4).Value)
    Next
    
    parks.trim
    
End Sub

This throws an error at `elements(size).card_no = new_card_no':
"Object variable or With block variable not set"
My expectation is that the park at elements(size) would have the properties I gave it.
I have tried using a property let, this results in the same error.
I have tried passing a park object and using:
Public Sub append(new_park as park)
    If UBound(elements) < size + 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve elements(size * 2)
    End If

    Set elements(size) = new_park
End Sub

This made the array populate but all elements would end up being the same as the last element.
Searching around hasn't been fruitful, so here I am.

In the append method, you haven't created a new instance of park.  Add Set elements(size) = New park

Declaring an array of type park doesn't automatically assign instances of park when the array is [re]sized: empty slots will just be Nothing

Thank you, Chris and Tim.
adding a new park statement in the loop in append works as expected.

Changing the append() function like so fixes the issue:
Public Sub append(new_card_no As String, new_entry_time As Date, new_exit_time As Date)
    If UBound(elements) < size + 1 Then
        ReDim Preserve elements(size * 2)
        
    End If
    
    Dim new_park As New park

    new_park.card_no = new_card_no
    new_park.entry_time = new_entry_time
    new_park.exit_time = new_exit_time
    
    Set elements(size) = new_park
    
    size = size + 1
End Sub

As Chris and Tim pointed out, the park objects in elements default to nothing and need to be instantiated before their properties can be set.

Maybe you could just use VBA Collection?
